# Calling function from another VC in Open Class - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function

I'm trying to call a function in another View Controller in my Open Class. The function essentially adds a subview to my view. I have been unsuccessful so far in calling the function. Here is the code for my Open Class:

```
open class ItemAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

override open func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if selected {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {

            print("show large icon")

            // smaller size
            self.mediumIconView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.2, y: 0.2)
            self.mediumIconView.alpha = 0

        }, completion: { (animating) in


            // Start showing large icon
            self.largeIconView.alpha = 0.2


            // double size + show large icon
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

                // double size
                self.largeIconView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(self.ENLARGE_MAX_SCALE), y: CGFloat(self.ENLARGE_MAX_SCALE))
                self.largeIconView.frame.origin.y = (1 - self.ENLARGE_MAX_SCALE) * self.MEDIUM_ICON_WIDTH - self.MEDIUM_ICON_WIDTH / 2 + 6
                // completely show large icon
                self.largeIconView.alpha = 1.0;

            }, completion: { (animating) in

                // a little smaller size
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {

                    // a little smaller size
                    self.largeIconView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(self.ENLARGE_FINAL_SCALE), y: CGFloat(self.ENLARGE_FINAL_SCALE))
                    self.largeIconView.frame.origin.y = (1 - self.ENLARGE_FINAL_SCALE) * self.MEDIUM_ICON_WIDTH - self.MEDIUM_ICON_WIDTH / 2 + 6
                }, completion: { (animating) in

                })

            })

        })

    } else {
        // normal size + hide large icon
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

            print("show small icon")

            // normal size
            self.largeIconView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)

            // hide large icon
            self.largeIconView.alpha = 0.0;
            self.largeIconView.frame.origin.y = -self.MEDIUM_ICON_WIDTH / 2

        }, completion: { (animating) in

            // show medium/small icon
            self.mediumIconView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
            self.mediumIconView.alpha = 1

        })

    }

}
```

}

I need to call the function when printing "Show large icon".

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1.** You can add a completion block to the open class:

```
typealias VoidBlock = () -> Void
open class ItemAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    var completionHandler: VoidBlock?
}
```

and the call that completion when your icon will be large:

```
// Start showing large icon
            self.largeIconView.alpha = 0.2
    //call completion 
    self.completionHandler?()
```

In your controller when your open class allocated put set the completion:

```
//not sure how are you doing this, so the code below is just my thoughts 
let itemAnnotationView = ItemAnnotationView()
itemAnnotationView.completionHandler = {
    //do something here when the icon is large
}
```

**Option 2.** The second way is to use a delegate

```
//define the protocol 
protocol ItemAnnotationViewDelegate {
    func iconDidBecomeLarge()
}
```

Then set the delegate var in your open class:

```
open class ItemAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView{
    var delegate: ItemAnnotationViewDelegate?
}
```

then call the delegate method when the icon is large:

```
// Start showing large icon

            self.largeIconView.alpha = 0.2
    //call the delegate method
self.delegate.iconDidBecomeLarge()
```

Now we need to set the delegate from your controller when your open class is allocated:

```
let itemAnnotationView = ItemAnnotationView()
    itemAnnotationView.delegate = self
```

setting the delegate requires your controller to conform the new protocol

You can set it as an extension:

```
extension YourCointroller: ItemAnnotationViewDelegate {
    func iconDidBecomeLarge(){
        //your icon is large now, do additional stuff
    }
}
```